# How do I fix 'You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar'?

Tags: github, terminal, homebrew

I ran: `brew doctor`

which returned following warning:

```
 Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
    Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  nettle
  libtasn1
  p11-kit
  gnutls
```

I have tried running `brew link nettle`, `brew link --dry-run nettle` and `brew link --overwrite nettle`

All of which returned

```
`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/nettle/3.4... Error: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`
```

Please could someone explain what this means and how to fix it?